# System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException.ToString() is Throwing an exception on deployment application

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to deploy an application with Sql Compact Server 3.5 but I get an error when I try to deploy it on another pc for any database request. Indeed, the deployment works on my dev computer.

The error is a `NullReferenceException` on :

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException.ToString()
```

But I've already followed the instructions on this link :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa983326.aspx (the private file–based deployment)

And I'm sure that I'm using the correct dll for my 32 bits application.

What could be my problem?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you locate and post the relevant src code?  Doesn't look like an installation issue but more like error-while-reporting-error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's an error-while-reporting-error but it only happen on another computer.

It's symply :

            `catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new ExceptionReadData(e.ToString());
            }`

For a request which normally works

Comment: In that case, ad logging and maybe use `throw new ExceptionReadData("Error reading", e);`

Comment: When I install this "http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5783" on the deployment computer, the error disappears so it's certainly an error with ressources.

But I want to make the second method works and not the first (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa983326.aspx)

Comment: Suggest you start by implementing proper execption handling: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/07/sql-server-compact-code-snippet-of-week.html